# ddl creating table even though ddl-auto is none

Tags: java, spring, hibernate

I have a spring project connected to a postgresql database. The connection is defined in this `application.yml` file:

```
spring:
  datasource: #TODO replace application.yml with an xml or java config file
    url: jdbc:${DBURL} #localhost/taskorchard
    username: ${DBUSER}
    password: ${DBPASSWORD}
  tomcat:
    max-wait: 20000
    max-active: 50
    max-idle: 20
    min-idle: 15
  jpa:
    hibernate:
      ddl-auto: none
    properties:
      hibernate:
        dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect
        format_sql: true
        id:
          new_generator_mappings: false
        jdbc:
          lob:
            non_contextual_creation: true

server:
   port: 8080 # This is the default port anyway, but you can change it here

security:
  jwt:
    token:
      secret-key: secret-key
      expire-length: 300000 # 5 minutes duration by default: 5 minutes * 60 seconds * 1000 miliseconds

UserController:
  signin: Authenticates user and returns its JWT token.
  signup: Creates user and returns its JWT token
  delete: Deletes specific user by username
  search: Returns specific user by username
  me: Returns current user's data
```

Note that the dialect is `org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect` and `ddl-auto` is set to `none`.

But when I run the program I see the following in my run window:

```
2019-10-26 16:20:15.021  INFO 3320 ... Using dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.H2Dialect
```

and get the error:

```
 2019-10-26 16:20:15.761  WARN 3320 ... Error executing DDL "create table toevent ...
```

So it is using the wrong dialect and executing a ddl command even though `ddl-auto` is set to `none`.

I thought it might be having trouble finding the application.yml in my resources folder because I was messing around with my source folders to set the test source folder, but I still have the resource folder set to the right thing as seen in these pictures:

Directory structure:
[image: directory structure]

Content roots:
[image]

But I'm concerned about the green highlighting behind part of the directory structure that wasn't there before.

What's going on? How do I make the `ddl-auto` and dialect work how it should?

Answer (score 0):

Well, I updated intellij and the problem was fixed. Don't know what exactly was going wrong. I guess intellij was just confused?